# node-telegram-bot-api disable links preview

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I've tried the following options, but I still see the link preview

```
await BOT.sendMessage(message.chat.id, uiMessage, menuOptions, {disable_web_page_preview: true })
```

```
await BOT.sendMessage(message.chat.id, uiMessage, menuOptions, { parse_mode: 'Markdown'})
```

```
await BOT.sendMessage(message.chat.id, uiMessage, menuOptions, { parse_mode: 'Markdown', disable_web_page_preview: true })
```

```
await BOT.sendMessage(message.chat.id, uiMessage, menuOptions, [{ parse_mode: 'Markdown'}, {disable_web_page_preview: true }])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `disable_web_page_preview` is part of the `options` parameter.

Looking at the [`sendMessage` documentation](https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api/blob/master/doc/api.md#TelegramBot+sendMessage):

```
chatId      Number|String   Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the target channel (in the format @channelusername)  
text        String          Text of the message to be sent  
[options]   Object          Additional Telegram query options
```

So you should extend `menuOptions` to also include `disable_web_page_preview`:

```
await BOT.sendMessage(message.chat.id, uiMessage, {disable_web_page_preview: true })
```

---

A litte snippet to test this:

```
const TelegramBot = require('node-telegram-bot-api');

const token = 'xxxxxxxx:AAEjLUL8Lx67lYEA3B2O7lSVhlCio3SVR9k';
const chatId = 12345678;

const bot = new TelegramBot(token, { polling: false });

bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Link Test');
bot.sendMessage(chatId, '[Foo Bar](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg)', { parse_mode: 'MarkDown', disable_web_page_preview: false });
bot.sendMessage(chatId, '[Foo Bar](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg)', { parse_mode: 'MarkDown', disable_web_page_preview: true });
```

Shows as:
[image]